# Yii Framework: list all files in directory

Tags: php, file, yii

I'm trying to check a directory and list all the files in there using the Yii Framework.
I tried the following:

```
$files = CFileHelper::findFiles(Yii::app()->basePath."/images/");
```

And I also tried:

```
$files = CFileHelper::findFiles("/images/");
```

Both of them return an error saying the the file or directory could not be opened. The directory is there - it is the default images directory and I am linking images from it. I am just not sure how to access its path in the context of the framework. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the path is `webroot/protected/images` your code should work.

If the path is `webroot/images` change your code to:

```
$files = CFileHelper::findFiles(Yii::app()->basePath."/../images/");
```

and this should work too.

```
$files = CFileHelper::findFiles(Yii::getPathOfAlias("webroot.images"));
```

Comment: Thank you! It was the webroot/images case and I should have though of the "/../" in front but alas. Appreciate you help!

Answer (score 0):

check the path: 
`echo Yii::app()->basePath."/images/";` 
actualy Yii::app()->basePath is your "protected" directory...

try this:

```
$files = CFileHelper::findFiles(Yii::getPathOfAlias("webroot.images"));
```